# A possible application of Tietze Extension Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

Given a normal topological space $(X, \tau)$ where $\tau$ is neither discrete nor indiscrete, a bounded non-constant continuous function $g$ defined on $X$ and a bounded non-constant continuous function $f$ defined on a closed set $A \subseteq X$. Fix $\epsilon > 0$. If we have $\|\,(f - g)\vert_A\,\|_{\infty} < \epsilon$, can we constructively extend $f$ to the entire space such that $\,\|f - g\,\|_{\infty} < \epsilon$. If such extension is not possible in a random normal topological space, how about the case when $(X, d)$ is a metric space? or in a compact metric space?

Originally I am working on the the case when $X$ is a metric space. In this case for any point $x \in X, X = \overline{\bigcup_{n \geq 1}B(x, n)}$. I do not know how to construct the extension of $f$ so that it will be uniformly close to $g$ in each ball. If this can be done on a metric space, I wonder if this can also be done on a normal space.

Comment: By Tietze the function $f-g$ can be extended from $A$ to $X$ while keeping it bounded by $\varepsilon$, call the extension $F$. Then $F+g$ is an extension of $f$ which is within $\varepsilon$ of $g$

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I can not imagine I miss this ....

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti Why not an official answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $f-g$ is continuous on $A$ and bounded by $\varepsilon$, so by the Tietze extension theorem it can be extended to a function $F\colon X\to \Bbb R$ while keeping it bounded by $\varepsilon$. But then $F+g$ is an extension of $f$ to $X$ which is within $\varepsilon$ of $g$.
Note that we didn't use any property of $X$ apart from being able to apply Tietze's theorem, so this works for any normal space $X$.

Comment: Officially thank you again for your answers!